# ajax textbox value no response auto suggestion

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create an auto-suggestion AJAX box but there is no response from the server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
<title></title>

    <?php
        include 'search.php';
    ?>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#textbox1").keyup(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "search.php",
            data: {textbox1: $(this).val()},
            success: function (data) {
                  $("#main").html(data);
            }
        });
      });
    });
    </script>

    <form method="POST">
              enter keyword to search<br>
              <input type="text" name="textbox1" id="textbox1">
              <br><br>
              <div id="main"></div>
    </form>

</head>
<body>
```

this is *search.php*

```
<?php

    include 'connection.php';

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $search_value = $_POST['textbox1'];
        $query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username LIKE '" . $search_value . "%'";
        $conn_status = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        while($row = $conn_status->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo $row['username'] . '<br>';
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: You're sending a GET request yet are using `$_POST`. Also note that your code is wide open to SQL injection. You should change it to use prepared statements to access your database ASAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Missed Following

1. Ajax Request is Get And you use POST request in PHP
2. Second is not matter but it is good practice if you define action in

Change Code As follow

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
<title></title>

    <?php
        include 'search.php';
    ?>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#textbox1").keyup(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "search.php",
            data: {textbox1: $(this).val()},
            success: function (data) {
                  $("#main").html(data);
            }
        });
      });
    });
    </script>

    <form method="POST" action="">
              enter keyword to search<br>
              <input type="text" name="textbox1" id="textbox1">
              <br><br>
              <div id="main"></div>
    </form>

</head>
<body>
```

Comment: At least give the OP some description of what you changed and why it helps. We're here to educate after all.